# How do I solve these "unresolved attribute references" when trying to create a world map?

Tags: python, pygal

I'm currently doing a Python project where I am creating a world map visualization that highlights North, South, and Central America in different colors. When I run the code, no world map file is created. All the places where there is the syntax `add` are highlighted and it says "unresolved attribute reference 'add' for class Worldmap()".

Also, the `render_to_file` in `wm.render_to_file` is highlighted and it says "unresolved attribute reference 'render_to_file' for class Worldmap".

What do these errors mean and how may I fix them and get the map created? I've already looked and applied the information in the link below when trying to fix this:
http://www.pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/types/maps/pygal_maps_world.html

Here is the relevant part of the code. I am using Python 3.9, Pygal 1.7, and the text editor Pycharms 2021.1.1 on a Mac.

```
import pygal

wm = pygal.Worldmap()
wm.title = "North, Central, and South America"
wm.add("North America", ["ca", "mx", "us"])
wm.add("Central America", ["bz", "cr", "gt", "hn", "ni", "pa", "sv"])
wm.add("South America", ["ar", "br" , "bo", "cl", "co", "ec", "gf", "gy", "pe", "py", "sr", "uy", "ve"])
wm.render_to_file("americas.svg")
```

This code comes from the book *Python Crash Course*. When the code within the book gave me those errors, I edited the code above to replicate the code within the link above such as having `pygal.maps.world.World()` instead of `pygal.Worldmap()`. It then gives me the error "cannot find references 'world() in __init.__py '

Comment: The documentation you link to seems to be for a different submodule than the one you are actually using in your code.

Comment: The code I shared above comes from the code instructed within the book Python Crash Course where the project I'm doing came from. When the code within the book gave me those errors,  I edited the code above to replicate the code within the link above such as having "pygal.maps.world.World()" instead of "pygal.Worldmap()." It then gives me the error "cannot find references 'world() in __init.__py ' ".

Answer (score 0):

The book author's web site notes that the library has been updated since the book went to press; their general comments and instructions are at https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/updates.html and the notes for Chapter 16 (which seems to be the one you are having trouble with) at https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_16/README.html#updates

Comment: I am the author of PCC. You're pointing to the right updates, but it should also be noted that the first edition of the book has been out of print for over two years now, so even those updates may be getting out of date.

Comment: I have downgraded my version of pygal from 2.2.3 to 1.7 to be able to use the original code in the book and it still won't display the world map. The only error I can see is that the "Worldmap" in "wm=pygal.Worldmap()" under the amercas.py file is highlighted and  says it "cannot find reference Wordmap in __init__.py"

Comment: Please update the question to reveal which precise version of the library you are using.